# discord.py slash permissions

Tags: python, discord, discord.py

How to add permissions to discord.py slash-commands command? There is no @has_permissions() in slash-commands.

````py
@slash.slash(
    name="kick",
    description="Kicks member from the server",
    options=[manage_commands.create_option(
        name = "member",
        description = "Who do you want to kick?",
        option_type = 3,
        required = True
        ),
        manage_commands.create_option(
        name = "reason",
        description = "What is the reason?",
        option_type = 3,
        required = False
        )])
async def _kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason='Unspecified'):
    await ctx.send(0)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    e=discord.Embed(title=" Banhammer has spoken", color=0xfa2d4c)
    e.add_field(name='Kick', value=f' :white_check_mark: Kicked {member} for `{reason}`', inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=e)```
````

Answer (score 2):

Since there is currently no permissions check for (discord-py-slash-command)[https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/], you can check within of your code if a member has a certain permission, as shown below

```py
@slash.slash(name="cool_command")
async def cool_command(ctx, option):
    if not ctx.author.guild_permissions.manage_messages: # replace this with your desired permission
        return # tell them they dont have permissions or raise an exception
    ... # do your stuff here
```

Answer (score 1):

Discord.py does not support slash commands yet.
Meanwhile, you can use [discord-py-slash-command](https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/) to use slash-commands.
Hope this helped

Answer (score 1):

Well, I tried out using `@commands.has_permissions()` and in my case it still worked. You can just try it out with a test command, it should respond:

> Interaction Failed

Let me know if it's not like that to you

Answer (score 0):

Now that there is slash command permissions when you generate your ouath2 token to invite the bot instead of just adding "bot" add "bot" and "applications.commands"

Discord.py has no actual support for slash command with just there api but theres a different one download here:

https://pypi.org/project/discord-py-slash-command/

Answer (score 0):

Below `@slash.slash(name=“Kick”, description=“Kicks the member”)`

Add:

```py
@commands.has_permissions(kick_members=True)
```

There you go. It should work

Answer (score 0):

To Do Slash Commands with dpy 2.0

You would need to register the commands **and** have application command scope in developer portal in order for this to work.
[image: Scope]

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord import app_commands

bot = commands.Bot(prefix="...")

@bot.event
async def on_ready():
    bot.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=...)) # id is guild id(s) 
    # Global bot.tree.sync()
    ...

@bot.tree.command(name="num")
    async def num(self, inter, number : app_commands.Range[int,10,12]):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your value is {value}', ephemeral=True)
```

Class method

```py
from discord.ext import commands

class Bot:
    def __init__(self, ...):
        ...

    async def on_ready(self): # Not recommended
        await self.tree.sync(guild=discord.Object(id=...))
        ...
```

Cogs:

```py
from discord import app_commands
from discord.ext import commands

class Cog(commands.Cog):
    def __init__(self, bot):
        self.bot = bot

    @app_commands.command(name="num")
    async def num(self, inter, number : app_commands.Range[int,10,12]):
        await interaction.response.send_message(f'Your value is {value}', ephemeral=True)

async def setup(bot):
    bot.add_cog(Cog(bot))
```

https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/interactions/api.html?highlight=app_commands#discord.app_commands.Range

Answer (score 0):

use @discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions(here enter your permissions), but you need to import from discord import app_commands

````
@slash.slash(
    name="kick",
    description="Kicks member from the server",
    options=[manage_commands.create_option(
        name = "member",
        description = "Who do you want to kick?",
        option_type = 3,
        required = True
        ),
        manage_commands.create_option(
        name = "reason",
        description = "What is the reason?",
        option_type = 3,
        required = False
        )])
@discord.app_commands.checks.has_permissions(manage_roles=True)
async def _kick(ctx, member: discord.Member, reason='Unspecified'):
    await ctx.send(0)
    await member.kick(reason=reason)
    e=discord.Embed(title=" Banhammer has spoken", color=0xfa2d4c)
    e.add_field(name='Kick', value=f' :white_check_mark: Kicked {member} for `{reason}`', inline=False)
    await ctx.channel.send(embed=e)```
````